# Javascript regex pattern for the Docker Image URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Javascript regex pattern for the Docker Image URL.

According to my research, the Docker image URL pattern is:
`<registry>/<repository>/<image>:<tag>`

Here are the components explained:

**registry (optional)**: The URL of the registry where the Docker image is hosted. This is optional, and if not provided, Docker assumes the image is on Docker Hub. Examples include **`docker.io`**, **`gcr.io`**, or a custom registry URL.

**repository (optional)**: The repository is a grouping for related Docker images. This is optional, and if not provided, it implies the "library" namespace on Docker Hub. Examples include **`nginx`**, **`ubuntu`**, or a custom repository.

**image**: The name of the Docker image within the repository. Examples include **`nginx`**, **`ubuntu`**, or a custom image name.

**tag (optional)**: The tag specifies a particular version or variant of the image. This is optional, and if not provided, Docker assumes the "latest" tag. Examples include `**latest`**, **`1.0`**, **`v1`**, **`020921`**, or a custom tag.

Here are some common patterns for Docker image URLs with related test cases (examples) that should check with Javascript regex:

**1. Docker Hub**:

- `<image>`
- `<user>/<image>`
- `<user>/<repository>/<image>`
- `<registry>/<user>/<repository>/<image>`

Example:

- `nginx`
- `username/nginx`
- `username/myrepo/nginx`
- `registry.example.com/username/myrepo/nginx`

**2. Private Registry**:

- `<registry>/<image>`
- `<registry>/<repository>/<image>`

Example:

- `registry.example.com/myimage`
- `registry.example.com/myrepo/myimage`

**3. With Tag**:

- `<image>:<tag>`
- `<user>/<image>:<tag>`
- `<registry>/<user>/<repository>/<image>:<tag>`

Example:

- `nginx:latest`
- `username/nginx:1.0`
- `registry.example.com/username/myrepo/nginx:2.0`

**4. Digest**:

- `<image>@<digest>`
- `<registry>/<image>@<digest>`

Example:

- `nginx@sha256:abc123def456...`
- `registry.example.com/myimage@sha256:xyz789uvw123...`

**5. URLs for Specific Registries**:

- `quay.io/<user>/<image>`
- `ghcr.io/<user>/<repository>/<image>`

Example:

- `quay.io/username/myimage`
- `ghcr.io/username/myrepo/myimage`

**6. Local Images**:

- `<image>:<tag>`
- `<repository>/<image>:<tag>`

Example:

- `myimage:latest`
- `myrepo/myimage:1.0`

Actually I've tried following regex to test Docker image URLs:

```
const dockerImage = /^(?<repository>[\w.\-_]+((?::\d+|)(?=\/[a-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+))|)(?:\/|)(?<image>[a-z0-9.\-_]+(?:\/[a-z0-9.\-_]+|))(:(?<tag>[\w.\-_]{1,127})|)$/gim;
```

But it didn't work properly in following situations:

```
dockerImage.test('http://example.example.com/ai-ocr:v1') //output: false , expected: true
dockerImage.test('example.example.com/crazymax/yasu') //output: false , expected: true
```

And it worked properly in this cases:

```
dockerImage.test('example.example.com/face-anonymizer:020921') //output: true , expected: true
dockerImage.test('example.example.com/operation_service_images/mohammad-mohammad') //output: true , expected: true
```

Thanks